Obtener tamaño en bytes de una lista de String en Java
Hola tego el siguiente error en Springboot: nested exception is com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 11534336 bytes.
tengo una lista en Java que almacena valores de tipo String me gustaría poder obtener el tamaño en bytes para poder iterar la lista por bloques, ya que no puedo hacerlo por cierto limite o cantidad de  registros, porque luego almaceno los valores en Datastore y aunque le ponga un limte de de 10 mil registos hay veces en las que excede la capacidad
Ejemplo:
List<String> values = getValues();

int limit = 10000;

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i += limit) {
//logic
}

la idea es no hacerlo por un bloque de cierta cantidad si no por 182967 bytes
espero puedann ayudarme saludos!

con el código que pusiste no se puede reproducir el problema, asegúrate de agregar la información suficiente para tener un [mcve]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385623/bytes-of-a-string-in-java
